# How are MessageBodyReaders used

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

Given something like:

e.g.

```
class User{
  String name;
  String someField1;
}

 @Consumes("some/media-type")
class ResourceA{

    public Response test(@FormParam("u") User u, @FormParam("f) String someField){
    }
}
```

Couple of questions:

1. Will a single `MessageBodyReader` used to de-serialize `User` or will each field in user be de-serialized by a different reader?
2. Is `@context` required on any/all of these?
3. Is `@FormParam` required on the fields in the `User` class?

I'm trying to understand if the server will take the list of readers available and for each param in test, check if ANY of the readers can de-serialize that type. Or if the first reader which matches the media type consumed is expected to de-serialize all the params.

If the server is iterating through each parameter and for each parameter finding the most appropriate reader, it kind of makes sense that the input stream being passed to `readFrom` is the same instance, and each reader is advancing through the input stream. Is this the case or am I totally misunderstanding how the `MessageBodyReader` is meant to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it works how I suspected.
Looking at the source for RESTEasy, the [MethodInjectorImpl](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/5047396653a4f392ff1f1c8a62453435ea3fb564/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/core/MethodInjectorImpl.java#L87) class uses the same request instance which has an input stream. For each parameter the injector discovers the most appropriate reader.

The input stream is not touched and is advanced by each reader which parses a value from the request.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this documentation on how [entity providers are selected](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#providers-selection). In particular:

> Procedure 7.2. MessageBodyReader Selection Algorithm
>
> 1. Obtain the media type of the request. If the request does not contain
>      a Content-Type header then use application/octet-stream media type.
> 2. Identify the Java type of the parameter whose value will be mapped
>      from the entity body. The Java type on the server is the type of the
>      entity parameter of the resource method. On the client it is the Class
>      passed to readFrom method.
> 3. Select the set of available MessageBodyReader providers that
>      support the media type of the request.
> 4. Iterate through the selected MessageBodyReader classes and,
>      utilizing their isReadable method, choose the first
>      MessageBodyReader provider that supports the desired combination of
>      Java type/media type/annotations parameters.
>
> If Step 4 locates a suitable MessageBodyReader, then use its
>   readFrom method to map the entity body to the desired Java type.
>
> Otherwise, the server runtime MUST generate a NotSupportedException
>   (HTTP 415 status code) and no entity and the client runtime MUST
>   generate an instance of ProcessingException.

@Context is not required and @FormParam does not need to be added to your bean - just to the REST resource method.

Comment: Thanks, I also found that in the spec and it answers a part of the question. https://jsr311.java.net/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-430004.2.1 - my misunderstanding however has been in #4, it says select the first one, but it sounds like it means the first one for a single param. If the resource accepts multiple params, does it repeat from 1? I think so but I'm unsure. The second thing that is unclear is the input stream, if it repeats from one, does the stream position stay the same (this would make sense) or get reset to 0 (makes less sense). But it's not entirely clear to me